# XSLT copy by attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, nodes

I have a problem. Cant get to copy only node with specific attribute in XSLT. My XML;

```
<root>
<mouse code="red"> .. </mouse>
<mouse code="blue"> .. </mouse>
<mouse code="green"> .. </mouse>
</root>
```

I am trying to copy only node with red attribute to get XML like this:

```
<root>
<mouse code="red"> .. </mouse>
</root>
```

Can this be done with simple XSLT transformation?

DeLuka

Comment: Your "XML" is not well-formed.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: No,`code=red` is not "corrected". Why does it matter? Because **I** had to correct it in order to test.

Comment: Strange, I am pretty sure it was corrected last time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="mouse[@code='red']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done simply with xsl:templates matching the node you want and using copy/copy-of.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mouse[@code='red']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, if there are other elements within mouse[@code='red'] then you'll need to handle them with another template.

Comment: This is not a good idea, because you are applying templates to **all** `mouse` nodes - and the built-in template rules will process them and write their text content to the output - see: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/94hvTyJ